# Python3 `keyboard` module, Docker in GitLab CI, Failed to Create a Device File Using uinput module

Tags: python-3.x, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My Python3 test script (which I want to run in a Docker container) uses the `keyboard` module.

In a Docker container (with `kbd` dependency), I am able to successfully execute the Python3 `keyboard` module methods (such as keyboard.press('a')).

I can only do so when providing the `-v "/dev/input:/dev/input"` option when I `docker run`. This mounts my local `/dev/input` directory to the container's `/dev/input` directory.

If I don't do this, attempts to use the `keyboard` module methods results in errors where devices or files do not exist.

Now, I want to run this test automatically in the GitLab CI/CD. I am using a shared runner provided by GitLab. When I do this, my job executes and I receive the following warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py:110: UserWarning: Failed to create a device file using `uinput` module. Sending of events may be limited or unavailable depending on plugged-in devices.
  device = aggregate_devices('kbd')
```

This causes my script to fail.

I provided a `config.toml` in the repository which specifies `volumes = ["/dev/input:/dev/input"]` but there appears to be no change in behavior when the CI launches my job.

Does `config.toml` only apply to privately hosted GitLab runners? The GitLab documentation was unclear in this aspect.

Any help would be appreciated.